# Convert NWPathMonitor into a string

Tags: swift, string, nwpathmonitor

This has me stumped, I am trying to get a the string of `NWPathMonitor`.
If I print `NWPathMonitor` I get this:

"**satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns**"

How can I get the same text in a string.

```
let interface = NWPathMonitor() // get the NWPathMonitor in a variable

let interfaceString = String(pathMonitor) // change that variable to a string
```

So the second line gives me "**No exact matches in call to initializer.**"

It's seems that `NWPathMonitor()` has a lot of info and I am not clearly specifying what I want.

Any idea how can I get the same line that prints "**satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns**" into a string variable?

Comment: have you tried: `let interfaceString = interface.currentPath.debugDescription`. Or, `interface.pathUpdateHandler = { path in   print("---> path: \(path.debugDescription)") }`

Comment: You say that if you print `NWPathMonitor`, you get "satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns". How exactly? `print(interface)` prints just "Network.NWPathMonitor".

Comment: Do you actually need that string? (""satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns")
I use the path.status and switch on this value to know if the path has a connection